# Make calling issue

Tags: android

- When i call from Android version 9 to received from another device but after some time lagging and crash the app.
- We are calling from any other Android version device then Call is Disconnected and showing message is 'Not Acceptable Here' from calling side and receiver side showing message is 'Request terminated'.
- When i Call and WI Fi is connected then showing same error like described in second number point.

**Logs**

```
-Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL) in tid 20211 (FinalizerDaemon), pid 20189 (jsip.pjsua2.app)

Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x18 in tid 24149 (Thread-313), pid 23869 (jsip.pjsua2.app)

-FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                    Process: com.dcs, PID: 9577
                                                    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no static method "Lorg/pjsip/pjsua2/pjsua2JNI;.SwigDirector_Call_onZrtpShowSAS(Lorg/pjsip/pjsua2/Call;J)V"
                                                        at org.pjsip.pjsua2.pjsua2JNI.swig_module_init(Native Method)
                                                        at org.pjsip.pjsua2.pjsua2JNI.<clinit>(pjsua2JNI.java:2902)
                                                        at org.pjsip.pjsua2.pjsua2JNI.new_Endpoint(Native Method)
                                                        at org.pjsip.pjsua2.Endpoint.<init>(Endpoint.java:69)
                                                        at com.dcs.pjsip.pjsua2.app.MyApp.<clinit>(MyApp.java:80)
                                                        at com.dcs.fragment.DialpadFragment.getDataCall(DialpadFragment.java:266)
                                                        at com.dcs.fragment.DialpadFragment.onViewCreated(DialpadFragment.java:72)
                                                        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performViewCreated(Fragment.java:2987)
                                                        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:546)
                                                        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:282)
                                                        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2189)
                                                        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2100)
                                                        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2002)
                                                        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$5.run(FragmentManager.java:524)
                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:233)
                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7212)
                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:499)
                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965)
```

I'll tried to implement PJSIP call using multiple way like Official site and other site to calling but make calling is not working. I want to create make call functionality both receive and called.

Comment: can you show your code to which logs point, without code it is difficult to help. In the logs you can find the info which means that you use a method which is not available for usage

Comment: This is my code for registration and make call

**Registration Code**
creds1.add(new AuthCredInfo("Digest", "*", username, 0,password));

**Make Call**
HashMap<String, String> item = (HashMap<String, String>) buddyListView.getItemAtPosition(buddyListSelectedIdx);

String buddy_uri = "sip:1054@test";

        MyCall call = new MyCall(account, -1);
        CallOpParam prm = new CallOpParam(true);

        try {
            call.makeCall(buddy_uri, prm);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            call.delete();
            return;
        }
        currentCall = call;